# libGDX Gwt inheriting from the wrong directory

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I'm having trouble with my libGDX HTML project: Whenever I try to run it in gwtDev mode it throws this exception:

[image]

I have a suspicion what might be wrong here: In the GdxDefinition.gwt.xml (code sample below) it inherits the main game with `<inherits name='CenaMain' />`

```
<module rename-to="html">
<inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gdx_backends_gwt' />
<inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.box2d-gwt' />

<inherits name='CenaMain' />
<entry-point class='com.t0ast.cena.client.HtmlLauncher' />

<set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="../android/assets" />
```

but I think it starts off in the wrong directory. It wants to inherit from `<pathToProject>\html\src` but the file it's supposed to inherit is located in `<pathToProject>\core\src`. How can I fix this? (As you might have noticed I'm a complete noob so please try to make your answer as easy as possible.)

Comment: Are you using an IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, Android Studio) or are you running ant manually?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 8.1 with the Gradle Support plugin

Comment: Ah, I've never used NetBeans unfortunately, https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans might help you a bit.

Comment: I think I didn't form my question clear enough: I'm trying to find a way to change the Gwt root folder (if possible directly in the `GdxDefinition.gwt.xml`). I'm not trying to change the Gradle settings.

Answer (score -2):

Well, turns out that I found the answer to my own question (I found it just a few days after I asked that question but then forgot to post it here):

Apparently, `gwtDev` and `gwtSuperDev` aren't supposed to work on their own. I had to use `htmlSuperDev`.